# how to get value of listview item in android

Tags: android

I am able to display litsview item in list i have only one item and i want to get that value on toast on item click but i am getting exception class cat exception .

```
    Myadapter adMyadapter = new Myadapter(EmployeeVisit.this, array);
                listview.setAdapter(adMyadapter);

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String keyword =(String)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                Log.v("value ", "result is " + keyword);
                Toast.makeText(EmployeeVisit.this,keyword, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


}
```

i just want to get value on toast which i am printing in listview please look where am doing wrong i am getting  class cast exception integer cannot convert in string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just change the code

```
String keyword =(String)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
```

to

```
String keyword=String.ValueOf(arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your array variable is global and use the code

```
String keyword =array [arg2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Write below code in your listview.setOnItemClickListener method:

```
Toast.makeText(EmployeeVisit.this,array[arg2], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

This will print value in the array at postion.

Note: arg2 is position in the listview. Make sure that your **array** should be declare as **final** or should be class variale, otherwise it will through error in setOnItemClickListener method

Answer (score 0):

```
 listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p_parent, View p_view, int p_position, long p_id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String keyword =((TextView)(p_view.findViewById(R.id.ulr_tvRow))).getText().toString();
            Log.v("value ", "result is " + keyword);



            Toast.makeText(EmployeeVisit.this,keyword, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

}

Replace "R.id.ulr_tvRow" with your row textview ID